# Manipulating data using apply functions

Tags: r, loops, apply, data-manipulation

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(20)
pay1<-sample(1:10,10,replace=TRUE)
pay2<-sample(1:10,10,replace=TRUE)
pay3<-sample(1:10,10,replace=TRUE)
gamematrix<-cbind(pay1,pay2,pay3)
gamematrix<-data.frame(gamematrix)
gamematrix



    pay1 pay2 pay3
1     9    8    5
2     8    8    1
3     3    1    5
4     6    8    1
5    10    2    3
6    10    5    1
7     1    4   10
8     1    2   10
9     4    3    1
10    4    9    7
```

Now, I want to create a new dataframe, that gives some weighting to the results above:

```
w=0.5
q_array<-data.frame(sapply(1:3,  function(x)  rep(0,10)))

for (i in 2:3){
  for (j in 1:10){
    q_array[j,i]=(1-w)*q_array[j,i-1]+w*gamematrix[j,i-1]
  }
}

   X1  X2   X3
1   0 4.5 6.25
2   0 4.0 6.00
3   0 1.5 1.25
4   0 3.0 5.50
5   0 5.0 3.50
6   0 5.0 5.00
7   0 0.5 2.25
8   0 0.5 1.25
9   0 2.0 2.50
10  0 2.0 5.50
```

In words: after first choice (which is always "0"), the q_array, gives equal weighting to the results from "gamematrix" and previous "q_array" result.

For example: Row 1 of q_array:

```
column 1 = 0 (by definition) 
column 2 = 0.5*0 + 0.5*9  = 4.5 
column 3 = 0.5*4.5 + 0.5*8 = 6.25
```

I know how to solve it using nested loops (presented here). 
But is there a faster and more elegant way, using for example apply functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `apply`:

```
myweights <- function(x,w) {
   y1 <- 0
   y2 <- w*y1+w*x[1]
   y3 <- w*y2+w*x[2]
   return(c(y1,y2,y3))
}
t(apply(gamematrix, 1, myweights, w=w))
```

which generates the following output:

```
        pay1 pay1
 [1,] 0  4.5 6.25
 [2,] 0  4.0 6.00
 [3,] 0  1.5 1.25
 [4,] 0  3.0 5.50
 [5,] 0  5.0 3.50
 [6,] 0  5.0 5.00
 [7,] 0  0.5 2.25
 [8,] 0  0.5 1.25
 [9,] 0  2.0 2.50
[10,] 0  2.0 5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

without loops and apply :

```
x <- gamematrix
lag1 <- function(x) cbind(0, x[, -ncol(x)]) # function to lag data.frame
p1 <- lag1(x) * (1-w)
result <- p1 + lag1(p1) * w
result
#    0 pay1 pay2
# 1  0  4.5 6.25
# 2  0  4.0 6.00
# 3  0  1.5 1.25
# 4  0  3.0 5.50
# 5  0  5.0 3.50
# 6  0  5.0 5.00
# 7  0  0.5 2.25
# 8  0  0.5 1.25
# 9  0  2.0 2.50
# 10 0  2.0 5.50
```